# C# Trackbar custom colors

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

this might be a very global question but here we go:

I was wondering how I could make a trackbar like Virtualbox.
They have a trackbar that have custom colors at the bottom to show if you've assigned too much  RAM to your virtual system.
Now my question is: How can I give my trackbar custom colors?
I have read something about e.graphics etc. and overriding other functions, but I can't seem to find any information about this ):.

If you know what I mean and have sources to good tutorials and/or examples that would be awesome! Because I really don't know where to look anymore :(.

I am programming in C#, WinForms.

Comment: You can use the TrackBarRenderer functionality, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484143/visual-styles-independent-drawing) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbarrenderer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Hans mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3752781/884410) the standard trackbar is pretty limiting.  You can change the [background color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx) through `TrackBar.BackColor` property.  Otherwise you will have to create a custom control and override the OnPaint method:

```
partial class MyTrackBar : System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar
{       
    protected override void  OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle([Brush color], ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

Third option is to use a trackbar already created.  Like [free CodeProject trackbar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14378/Advanced-TrackBar-Slider-Control-with-MAC-Style-C) or [commercial Devexpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Editors/Editors/RangeTrackBarControl.xml) one.

Comment: Thanks, I might create a control myself then. Good exercise too I guess :). Thanks!